# Ansible - replace first occurrence of certain expression in file - path includes hostname

Tags: replace, ansible

I need to replace the first occurrence of a certain string in a specific file.

I think about to use the replace module of Ansible for this.

```
- hosts: abc
  tasks:
  - name: Replace first occurence of specific string
    replace:
      path: /etc/config/abc_host/application.yml
      regexp: 'Unix'
      replace: "Linux"
```

This would replace all occurences of `Unix` with `Linux` in this specific .yml-file. But I also have some other hosts (def_host, ghi_host etc.) for which I would I like to replace only the first occurrence of `Unix` with `Linux`.

So, there are two issues to solve:

First, using the hostnames as variable in path. Instead of hard-coding abc_host.yml I want something like `path: /etc/config/($host)_host/application.yml`.

Second, I just want to replace the first occurrence of the specific string (and not any other following occurrences of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the host variable you can use inventory_hostname or inventory_hostname_short depending on how much of the name you need.   inventory_hostname has the full name and the short has the name to the first period.

I've not tried this in Ansible but this may work

```
replace:
  regexp: '^(.*?\.)Unix([.\n]*)$'
  replace: '\1Linux\2'
```